# Terminal: Rename multiple files to be in numerical order

Tags: command-line, rename

I have a lot of files that I need to rename in numerical order. So what I have is this

```
Getting Started 1.jpg
Getting Started 10.jpg
Getting Started 100.jpg
Getting Started 101.jpg
Getting Started 102.jpg
```

and what I want to do is rename them so that they are ordered like

```
Getting Started 001.jpg
Getting Started 002.jpg
Getting Started 003.jpg
Getting Started 004.jpg
```

is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .bsh file inside the directory in which your images are stored and paste the below code :

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1

for file in *.jpg
do
    new=$(printf "Getting Started %03d.jpg" "$count")
    mv -- "$file" "$new"
    (( count++ ))
done
```

Open a Terminal and navigate to the directory in which your script is stored.

To change the permissions of the script :

```
chmod +x <filename>.bsh
```

To execute the script :

```
bash <filename>.bsh
```

**Note:**
`%03d` sets pad to length of 3

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* way to do it is to use a purpose-made application, such as [PyRenamer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/pyrenamer/)

```
sudo apt-get install pyrenamer
```